# Login session sync between chrome extension and website

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito

**Background:**

- We have developed a Chrome extension with AWS backend, where AWS Cognito handles user authentication. Users can sign in from the extension popup.
- We also built a mostly static website, where only some guides and information about the extension is presented to the public. No login is required here.
- Everything works fine.

**What we need to do now:**

We're adding a new feature to the system that would require a small minority of our users to login to the website too. So, for this small group of users, we'd need the website to sync up with the extension so that the login session is the same between the site and the extension.

I'm aware that I can make all users sign in from the website instead of the extension popup, and then use a session cookie to be read by the extension. But I'd prefer not to implement this approach as the vast majority of users won't have anything to do the website, and we don't want to redirect them there just to sign in.

***So, my question is:*** is there any elegant way to have the website and the chrome extension sync up on the user login session, given that all users use the extension to login first?

Comment: Can you make the website only available from the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this is how multiple tabs for the same website work. It's called session management and most authN providers support this out of the box. If your extension is using an authentication provider, it is likely providing session management as well. Then just reuse that in the website.